# Modify in original object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have define an object in variable "c". I have also make a function in which I passed a object. When I do changes in that variable it is also changing original object but my concern is why below given statement is not working with that object. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxm0oda8/)

```
function changeParam(x, y, z) {
  x = 3;
  y = "new string";
  z["key2"] = "new";
  z["key3"] = "newer";

  z = {"new" : "object"};
}

var a = 1,
    b = "something",
    c = {"key1" : "whatever", "key2" : "original value"};
var m=c;
changeParam(a, b, c);

console.log(c)
console.log(m)
```

Comment: "When passing in a primitive type variable like a string or a number, the value is passed in by value. This means that any changes to that variable while in the function are completely separate from anything that happens outside the function." - http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: Which statement are you asking about specifically? And, what do you mean by "not working?" What do you expect to happen?

Comment: if we are adding key3 in that object then it is there but when we are asign whole new object to "z" then it is not working

Comment: What do you use `x` and `y` for? They seem to be totally useless.

Comment: I think I have found an answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript passes object by reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314911/1950327) To pass it by value you need to clone it before.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) you'll find options of doing it. There are a lot ways of doing it, each with advantages and disadvantages. Depends on what you want from your object you can choose one.

Shortest way is to stringify object to JSON and parse again. (note that you can not save function in such object):

```
var newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject));
```

Works well with your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7usc3v1/)

If you are using jquery in your project, you could use "jquery way" as well:

```
var newObject =  jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```